# MongoDB query or programmatic solution

Tags: java, mongodb, algorithm, bigdata, database

I am fairly new to big data and we have millions of records that has the data in the following way -

```
ID    Timestamp    Status
1.      12:00:00.      ON
1.       12:00:35.      Off
1.       12:01:01.      ON
1.        12:10:00.     Off
1.        12:11:00.      On
```

I need to calculate the total time it was off. This is across millions of records so the solution has to be fast. Any thoughts on what I could do either algorithmically or through queries? I figure one way is to iterate the data through an array but that just seems too time consuming and I am sure people have done this before.

Comment: What is the data format? You say iterate through array - what's the array?  Can you include an actual document that's in the DB?  Also are the events guaranteed to be ordered and unique?  I.e. you cannot have OFF after another OFF or you can?

Comment: 1. The data format is json since it's stored in mongodb.

Comment: 1. When I meant array, what I was trying to say was I can write a query that returns and insert that data in an array using java. I will have to setup a test doc and I can do that at home. I only put the relevant document but I can guarantee that they are unique. And yes you can have another off after another off since some other column got updated.

Comment: you need to include a sample document since you are not describing its structure very clearly.

Comment: Basically I am trying to find something like LAG or LEAD function in mongodb. Is there a way to do that? As in lookup previous or next row in mongodb?

Comment: again, include an actual sample document (which will show what types you are using), otherwise there is not enough information here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two aggregations, one that gets the sum of the timestamps for OFF and one that gets the sum of the timestamps for ON (normalize everything to seconds since some fixed date, pick something recent to avoid overflow if possible, though the calculations will be with the double type, so you've got some breathing room). Then subtract the sum of ON timestamps from OFF timestamps. As long as they're all paired up right (you have one OFF for every ON), this will be the right answer.

That's because you can rewrite the sum

[image]

where the 'b's are OFF events and the 'a's are ON events.

To do this with the aggregation framework, something like this can work to do the summations, assuming your documents are of the form `{_id: <id>, timestamp: <ts>, status: <'ON'|'OFF'>}`:

```
db.coll.aggregate({$group: {_id: '$status', total: {$sum: '$timestamp'}}})
```

Comment: this doesn't work conceptually when 'on' and 'off' states aren't paired - 'off' can follow 'off' it seems (according to clarifying comment).  In addition, sum is only allowed for numbers, so if timestamp is stored as anything but a number, your "total" will be 0.